# What Material Component is used here in the Permissions Guidelines?

Tags: material-design

In the Material permissions request patterns [guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/permissions.html#permissions-request-patterns), there is the following example.

[image: example]

Wondering what that bottom component is (the one with "No Thanks" and "Try it" buttons).

- Could be a Snackbar, but [guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage) clearly state 0-1 actions and these has 2.
- Could be a [Modal Bottom Sheet](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#), but it's not really a list or a grid and it doesn't come up as a result of user interaction, so again, seems contradictory to the guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of fact it's one of your links: It's a dialog on a Modal Bottom Sheet:

> Modal bottom sheets are alternatives to menus, or simple dialogs, and
>   can display deep-linked content from another app. They appear above
>   other UI elements and must be dismissed in order to interact with the
>   underlying content. When a modal bottom sheet slides into the screen,
>   the rest of the screen dims, giving focus to the bottom sheet.

Your particular screen is the result of a previous action (map search) and the original screen is the one below (note the [**persistent bottom sheet**](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-persistent-bottom-sheets)):

[image]

Since you need to provide a permission, a dialog appears in a modal bottom sheet (it could be just a regular dialog as well)

Either way, to the risk of being repetitive, remember: **Material Design is a set of guidelines, nothing else**. It's not like if you do something different it will be necessarily wrong (I use the exact opposite to Material's button guidelines and it works way better than those guidelines)

Comment: I guess what confused me is that in subsequent descriptions, modal bottom sheets always seem to be referred to as containing "menu items", I had missed the dialog bit.